# Timer Job not running

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I created a custom timer job and deployed it into my development farm (MOSS 2007). The job runs fine. The thins is that after I deployed it to the QA farm. The status of the job says succeeded in central admin, but nothing happens. I added extra logging and nothing is being logged.

I thought it was something with that specific timer job, so I created another timer job that just has an assert and displays a pop up when it runs. Again, it just in the dev farm but not in the QA one. In this case though, the status of the job says Initialized and 0% completed, but no pop up.

I think it has something to do with permissions, but I cannot find what it is. Any toughts??

Comment: Have you restarted the SharePoint Timer service? My newly deployed Timer Jobs rarely run until I restart the service.

Comment: Yes, I even restarted the server. Weird thing here is that the job says that it ran, but nothing happens

Comment: I tested it in another environment. It worked ok, then failed. I modifed the timer to run in a different Web Application and it worked. It looks like the Web application is malfunctioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked again after clearing the cache of the SharePoint server. 
I followed this [steps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/josrod/archive/2007/12/12/clear-the-sharepoint-configuration-cache-for-timer-job-and-psconfig-errors.aspx)