# Timer Jobs don't run after changing the schedule

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I created a custom timer job. It used to run fine during development an initial testing when I using SPMinutSchedule for scheduling it every minute of 5 minutes. The intention is to run it once a day in production. So, I changed the schedule using SPDailySchedule and it stopped running. I kind of fixed it by clearing the cache of the server each time I change the schedule.

I deploy the job using a feature with Web Application scope.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timer Job not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197194/timer-job-not-running)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1):

From REF:  http://www.mstechblogs.com/shailaja/reschedule-or-change-the-interval-of-a-sharepoint-custom-timer-job/

To reschedule or change the interval of a SharePoint custom Timer Job

- Change the schedule interval in the custom code using the
  SPDailySchedule class of the SharePoint object model
- Build and deploy in the GAC.
- IISRESET
- Go to the command prompt and navigate to the 12 hive of SharePoint
- Uninstall the existing Timer feature, for example, stsadm.exe –o uninstallfeature –filename yourfeaturename\feature.xml
- Install the new Timer feature, for example, stsadm.exe –o installfeature –filename yourfeaturename\feature.xml
- Go to the windows services and restart the Windows SharePoint Services Timer